# How to search Google Drive for Docs and Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, google-docs

I have been using Google Drive for several years. At this moment, I have a very robust folder structure there, with many files of various types, altogether more than 13 GB. Now I need to search my Drive for all .gdoc and .gsheet files. With so many files on my Drive, it is almost impossible to do it manually. I know how to search Google Drive for all "text documents" (or for all "spreadsheets") but this gives me also all .docx, .odt, .txt and so on (.xlsx, .ods and so on) files. This is not what I want, I need to filter only .gdoc and .gsheet files.

Comment: After doing some cursory testing, have you tried using a `NOT` operator in your search and exempt .xlsx, .docx, etc? For instance, `type:document` brings up Google Docs as well as .docx files. Using `type:document NOT *.doc OR *.docx` removed Word docs from the search results.

Comment: Thank you, this workaround worked. Just for amusement, I had to type these two commands: "type:spreadsheet NOT *.xlsx NOT *.xls NOT *.ods" and "type:document NOT *.docx NOT *.doc NOT *.pdf NOT *.txt NOT *.odt NOT *.bbl NOT *.blg NOT *.aux NOT *.snm NOT *.out NOT *.nav NOT *.tex NOT *.tcp NOT *.tps NOT *.ipe NOT *.svn-base NOT *.civBeyondSwordWBSave NOT *.spl NOT *.brf NOT *.vrb NOT *.pgn NOT *.ini".

Comment: Use `AND` to group things. You can also sync Drive to your computer and then you can search by extension type. It just doesn't run that way on Drive because they're not actually documents.

Answer (score 10):

There's an updated version of this now. You can search by apps, so you can just put:

```
app:"Google Sheets"
```

And

```
app:"Google Docs"
```

Comment: As of december 2017 this does not seem to work.

Comment: As of January 2019, this works. Try https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/search?q=app:%22Google%20Docs%22. Also, you can search for `app:"Google Drawings"`.

Comment: Works, and so does `type:spreadsheet`. Probably the latter will find XLSX and ODS documents as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `type:spreadsheet` in your query.

Works with: spreadsheet, presentation, drawing, image, video, pdf

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, I found out why app:"Google Docs" did not work for me.

You seem to have to type exactly the words it is translates to in your language. I wish to have Google in English, but since I live in the Netherlands, it automatically chooses Dutch as language.

So instead of searching for app:"Google Docs", I have to search for app:"Google Documenten" and then it finds everything.

[image: If you click the arrow near the search box, and click on Types, you can see the names of the extensions in your native language (so Documenten for Dutch)]

Then you type app:"Google 'thing in your native language you want'"
So for example:

- app:"Google Documenten"
- app:"Google Presentaties"
- app:"Google Spreadsheets"

for Dutch.